# Nginx wss + tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, websocket

We run nginx and tomcat on the same server.
Nginx terminates ssl and upstreams everything to tomcat.
All connections are websockets. Some clients experience a problem when ws connection is dropped, restored, but doesn't appear on tomcat backend server.
Even though nginx shows that connection is established with the client.

In the logs we see this:
2017/08/25 19:05:53 [info] 21059#0: *157252 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while proxying upgraded connection, client: 172.22.1.1, server: , request: "GET /commands HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8083/ccs/ws-commands", host: "example.com:8443"

Any thoughts?

Here's the nginx config

```
    #user  nginx;
    #worker_processes  3;
    worker_processes  16;
    worker_rlimit_nofile  64000;

    error_log  /srv/logs/nginx/error_log info;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


    events {
        worker_connections  4096;
    }


    http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main    '[$time_local] $remote_user - $remote_addr:$remote_port -> $upstream_addr '
                        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                        '$request_time';


    access_log  /srv/logs/nginx/nginx.log main;
    client_body_temp_path /tmp;
    proxy_temp_path /tmp;
    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp;
    scgi_temp_path /tmp;


    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  180;

    proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
    proxy_send_timeout 5m;
    proxy_read_timeout 5m;

  # Support for WebSocket proxying (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html)
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      ''      close;
    }

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS;

    include conf.d/*.conf;
    }
```

server conf:

```
  upstream server {
    server localhost:8083;
  }
  server {
    listen       8443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate    ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    ssl/example.com.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://server;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
    location /status {
        return 200;
    }
    location / {
        return 404;
    }
  }
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: This timeout should translate back to 502 or something on the client side?

Comment: Any chance you can try with a more modern Tomcat? What is your connector configuration in Tomcat? Tomcat 7 still supports blocking I/O connectors, which, when used with websocket (which is a actually valid configuration), pretty much ruin everything.

Comment: Eventually, we found it's kinda weird communication between nginx + some flaws in java app. 
I decreased read timeout to 60s and everything works just fine.